# Why does my Chrome Extension stop working when I restart Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome Extension that works perfectly after I upload it to Chrome using the 'Load unpacked' button.

However, when I quit and reopen Chrome, the extension does not interact with the webpages at all. If I reload the extension, (or sometimes just click the extension icon) it immediately works again.

My code uses content scripts and a background.js script. After I've restarted Chrome, anything inside

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
});
```

does not run.

Why does my extension stop working when I restart Chrome?

Comment: Are you sure you want onInstalled? That will only ever run once, as in ever ever. Not once per browser session, but one time right after it has been installed (or on browser or extension update). Maybe you mean [onStartup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onStartup)?

Comment: I absolutely did want onStartup, thank you for your help, that's exactly what I was missing.